# Where is layer stacking from merge raster tool of qgis?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal-merge, qgis-2.18

In the newest version of Qgis (2.18) there isn't layers stack option in order to merge raster bands. So tried to merge Landsat bands in only one file and I couldn't.

What can I do to stack bands of landsat in only one file in Qgis 2.18 now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The name of the option `Layer stack` has been changed to `Place each input file into a separate band` as [shown here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/c69665be927056908652b966728a6c98224b0032):

[image: stack option changed]